# inno pass multiple variables from code to run

Tags: parameters, inno-setup

How can I pass two variables from [Code] section to Parameters in [Run] section in Inno Setup?

Basically, I want to do the following.

- Get a path and save user input to a variable in a procedure InitializeWizard.
- Get a file and its complete path and save user input to a second variable in a second InitializeWizard procedure.
- Pass the user input, both the first path and the file with its path to a batch file in [Run] section.

I really don't find how to put this into inno script:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: shellexec postinstall skipifsilent; Parameters: "{code:GetBatchParams GetBatchParams2}"


[Code]
var
  DirInputPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  DirInputPage2: TInputDirWizardPage;
function GetBatchParams(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := DirInputPage.Values[0];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  DirInputPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpWelcome, 'Set Oracle kit path', '', 
    '', False, '');

  DirInputPage.Add('Choose the location of Database folder as extracted from Oracle kit archives:');
  DirInputPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{src}');
end;

function GetBatchParams2(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := DirInputPage2.Values[0];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard2;
begin
  DirInputPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpWelcome, 'Set qpay interface path', '', 
    '', False, '');

  DirInputPage.Add('Choose the location of ear file:');
  DirInputPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{src}');
end;
```

thanks

edit:
I made some modifications in order to reflect my needs (one folder, one file). I don't know how to pass them both as parameters for the executable file (I don't know how to write the code directive in order to make the installer start both those wizards)

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: shellexec postinstall skipifsilent; Parameters: "{code:GetBatchParams GetBatchParams2}"


[Code]
var
  DirInputPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  FileInputPage: TInputFileWizardPage;

function GetBatchParams(Value: string): string;

begin
  Result := DirInputPage.Values[0];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  DirInputPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpWelcome, 'Set Oracle kit path', '',  '', False, '');        
  DirInputPage.Add('Choose the location of Database folder as extracted from Oracle kit archives:');
  DirInputPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{src}');
end;


function GetBatchParams2(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := FileInputPage.Values[0];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  FileInputPage := CreateInputFilePage(wpWelcome, 'Set qpay interface path', 'where is war', '');
  FileInputPage.Add('Location of ear file:', 'Executable files|*.ear|All files|*.*', '.ear');

end;
```

Comment: Simply concatenate them into one string in just one getter.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I didn't make myself clear: this variables are two different things, one represent the location of a folder the other is the location of an .ear file. First will be used for silent installation of a database the other for silent installation of an interface in webpshere.

Comment: But they specify just one complex command line parameter. Well, if you really want to go that way, then use `Parameters: "{code:GetBatchParams} {code:GetBatchParams2}"`, but in my view it's misleading and I would concatenate all those parameters in one getter (from which you can call all those subfunctions and concatenate them e.g. by using `Format` function).

Comment: I made one single function where both parameters are read from user input but now I have to concatenate them in order to pass them one after other (including a space between them). Something like   Result := DirInputPage.Values[0]  "" FileInputPage.Values[0]; Any hint how can I do this?

Comment: `Result := Format('%s %s', [DirInputPage.Values[0], FileInputPage.Values[0]])` will produce string consisting from `DirInputPage.Values[0]` followed by the space followed by the `FileInputPage.Values[0]`. But don't you need some `"` enclosing chars ?

Comment: thanks! that was the missing part. now it should work. (what " enclosing chars do you mean?)

Comment: Command line parameters specifying file paths are usually enclosed in `""` chars. The code I've posted doesn't enclose those values. If you'd need that, modify the format string to be like `'"%s" "%s"'`, but it depends on what command you want to execute.

Comment: I used this until now only with one parameter (folder) and it worked, I guess it will work now with 2 parameters just fine.

Comment: Don't guess, test.  And especially test with paths that contain spaces, becase as @TLama said you'll almost certainly need to quote those.